# Generating PDF/Excel reports from a c# .net web application

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, reporting

We have a system that is used by a few hundred separate customers, at the end of the month the customer likes to generate a report of the activity with his/her clients. These reports are nothing special; they maybe contain a logo, address and a few lines of mathematical data. Currently we use Crystal Reports but that is just not a pleasant experience ;) also seems like a bit of overkill as we use something like 1% of its functionality.

What have other people used to generate reports from a web application, PDF generation is a must.

Answer (score 1):

Well, we use CR as well. I have heard about [iTextSharp](http://itextsharp.sourceforge.net), and have seen it used for pdf concatenation in our systems. Maybe thats what you look for. For Excel report generation we use csv format for simple tabular data and [COM interop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173186(VS.80).aspx) for more advanced reports.

Answer (score 1):

If you just need to generate a PDF file you could use a library like [ABCpdf.NET](http://www.websupergoo.com/purchase.htm#abcpdfnet). It's around $329 per license but is easy to use and quite reliable.

Answer (score 0):

We use SQL Server Reporting Services (SSRS). Reports are built in Visual Studio.
[link text](http://www.microsoft.com/sql/reporting/)

Answer (score 0):

While evaluating some of the web control suites for a decent grid, I noticed some of them had export to xls/csv/pdf built in.

Answer (score 0):

For generating PDF output I've always used FOP or [nFOP](http://sourceforge.net/projects/nfop).  It's a pretty good open source XSL:FO processor.

Answer (score 0):

Always use SQL Reporting here, but if you want to create the PDFs manually then iTextSharp is pretty mature.  It's actually a port of the iText Java library, so Googling for that usually turns up plenty of documentation and examples to play around with.